# SQL While Loop where field is not Equal to

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to run a loop in SQL that loops untill a field is found that equals to something. for example

```
while exists (select account from #nodes where account IS NOT EQUAL TO 'STRATERGY')
```

But I dont know how to do this, I want it to loop untill it finds the word STRATERGY in one of the fields in the account column.

Can Anyone lend a hand?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do, seems a strange way of finding a record.

Comment: sybase or t-sql? why do you need to loop in the first place? there is usually a superior/simpler set based operation

Comment: Im using sybase, The loop uses a file structure system with every file stored in the database as a to and from. So it says the file in the from and where it goes to and vise versa. I need to go from the bottom of the structure to the top so im using a procedure to to get the to then put them in a temp table then loop through and go up through the system. I want to keep all the files in the system from bottom to top in a table. Hope that makes some kind of sence... so when it gets to stratergy it would stop

Comment: @sam Ember, I think you have to use a cursor instead of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query I am assuming you have to do some actions on each account which is equal to 'STRATERGY'. If so use a cursor instead of loop.

If I my assumption is wrong please check [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/24/sql-server-simple-example-of-while-loop-with-continue-and-break-keywords/)

something like this.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
select @intFlag =count(*) from #nodes where account IS NOT EQUAL TO 'STRATERGY'
WHILE (@intFlag >1 )
BEGIN
PRINT @intFlag
select @intFlag =count(*) from #nodes where account IS NOT EQUAL TO 'STRATERGY'
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use not equal to same as it was in C language, java, C# etc.

```
declare @n int
set @n=5
while @n !=0
begin
    print @n
    set @n=@n-1
end
```